# Get CSS Browser Uses for required in html5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am currently working on an application that uses both html5 required tags and the jquery validation plugin to make sure all fields are filled in prior to a form submission.  I would like the error messages to look the same, but I don't really know where to begin looking for the styling each browser uses to handle the required tag in html5. Is there any way to grab the CSS that a browser uses for the required tag? (I could just hardcode a .required class myself, but I'd like to at least find the styling for one browser because from what I've seen they are all nicer than what I know how to make!)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd have a look in the object inspector / firebug to see what happens in style attributes, then create css instructions that replicate those attributes for a given class name.

Comment: I tried to do that before posting, but part of the problem is that as a relatively new developer I'm not sure what I'm looking for here.  Also, I didn't see any changes to the style of the element when using firebug, but I assume that's because I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try to grab these styles with your browser inspector (F12 in Chrome or right click -> inspect element, but I don't know if you can target it). If you are a new developer as you said you might find [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil?hl=en) Chrome plugin very handy. It allows you to send styles of the last checked element (with inspector) to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Anyway if you can't target the message with the inspector you can find default styles for **webkit** based browsers [Here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), just search for `::-webkit-validation-bubble`

Comment: @iamthereplicant You are welcome. If it answered your question consider voting up this answer and accepting it. See StackOverflow [IntroTour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Chrome uses a "callout" type shape. It isn't exactly the same, but you can create something similar on this site: http://csstooltip.com/

In Firefox, what you need to do is create a sample page, right click on the element (input field) and select "Inspect Element". After you do that you should be able to click the "Computed styles" tab on the right side of your screen and you can select the check box at the bottom that says "Browser styles". This will show you what the browser does.

By the way, in case you need some test code that you can run really easily, the following should work well:

```
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>

    <body>
        <form name="input" action="#" method="get">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="example"/>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="example" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        <form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!